# Grails 2.0.3 HSQLDB

Tags: grails, grails-orm, hsqldb

I was creating a grails application using Grails 2.0.3 but I want to use HSQLDB the database repository.
The reason of having to return back to HSQLDB instead of using the default database repository of Grails 2.0+, H2, IReport of Jaspersoft doesn't having H2 support.

I've tried to add the H2 plugin to IReport or use the Netbeans and include both the IReport and H2 plugins, both didn't work.

My questions are:

1. Am I going to import the library[.jar] of HSQLDB to the lib of the project?
2. Am I going to change the driverClassName? [What name would it be?]
3. What's the default port of HSQLDB if its going to be within the localhost?
4. Aside from the including `runtime 'hsqldb:hsqldb:1.8.0.10'` in the dependencies closure of `app/conf/BuildConfig.grovvy` do I still need to download the HSQLDB Server?
5. I am used in using H2, when I use HSQLDB instead, is/are there changes/concerns I must be aware of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. runtime 'hsqldb:hsqldb:1.8.0.10' in BuildConfig.groovy will be enough
2. driverClassName = "org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"
3. Specify connection url according to your requirements, e.g.: "jdbc:hsqldb:mem:devDB" - to use in-memory DB, "jdbc:hsqldb:file:prodDb;shutdown=true" - to use file based server

Comment: If I am going to use the in-memory DB of HSQLDB, how am I going to connect IReport to that database? I've tried to use "jdbc:hsqldb:mem:sampleDB" as the url of the connection in the Services Tab of IReport and cannot locate the server from the two schemes `Info...` and `Public`.

Comment: To connect from other processes, you need to run an HSQLDB server with the in-memory database.